# In Game of Thrones season 2-3, why were Frey's soldiers (possible spoilers)?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Warning: Spoilers from season 2 and season 3 below:

> In season 2 Walder Frey pledges his troops to Robb Stark in exchange for him marrying one of his daughters. He also allows passage over the river. In season 3, Robb Stark wants to take Casterly Rock but he has lost too many troops. So he needs more, and the only one that give him those troops is Walder Frey. But I would think those soldiers should already have been with him.

**Q: Why weren't Walder Frey's soldiers already part of Robb Stark's army?**

Comment: Robb did already have a big army at that point, so most likely not all of the Frey troops joined him.

Comment: ISTR he lost Frey's troops when he married that other girl?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They left when Robb married Talisa. However in the book this was another girl, [Jeyne Westerling](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jeyne_Westerling). From *A Storm of Swords:*

> “Your wife is lovely,” Catelyn said when they were out of earshot,
>   “and the Westerlings seem worthy... though Lord Gawen is Tywin
>   Lannister’s sworn man, is he not?”
>
> “Yes. Jason Mallister captured him in the Whispering Wood and has been
>   holding him at Seagard for ransom. Of course I’ll free him now, though
>   he may not wish to join me. We wed without his consent, I fear, and
>   this marriage puts him in dire peril. The Crag is not strong. For love
>   of me, Jeyne may lose all.”
>
> **“And you,” she said softly, “have lost the Freys.”**
>
> **His wince told all. She understood the angry voices now, why Perwyn
>   Frey and Martyn Rivers had left in such haste, trampling Robb’s banner
>   into the ground as they went.**
>
> “Dare I ask how many swords come with your bride, Robb?”
>
> “Fifty. A dozen knights.” His voice was glum, as well it might be.
>   When the marriage contract had been made at the Twins, old Lord Walder
>   Frey had sent Robb off with a thousand mounted knights and near three
>   thousand foot. “Jeyne is bright as well as beautiful. And kind as
>   well. She has a gentle heart.”
>
> It is swords you need, not gentle hearts. How could you do this, Robb?
>   How could you be so heedless, so stupid? How could you be so... so
>   very... young.

*(Bolded the important parts of the quote.)*

Comment: This is what I was looking for. They don't make it clear in the TV series that Frey soldiers were already with him and left after Robb marries Talisa. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 8):

The Frey men were pledged to Robb in exchange for Robb marrying one of the Frey daughters. When Robb married Talisa instead, that pretty much ended their deal, so the Frey men went back to Walder, just like Karstarks men left Robb after he beheaded him.

Answer (score 1):

When Robb promised that he'd marry one of Walder's daughters, the Freys joined the War of the Five Kings at the side of Robb.

This means that a lot of the Frey soldiers went with Robb at the War. But, Walder needed some soldiers with him at the Twins to guard them.

Also, at the books it mentioned that Walder Frey isn't the most reliable person. He always wants to be on the winning side. For instance, at King Robert's rebellion, he joined the side of Robert *only* after Robert had defeated Rhaegar, meaning that the war was won.

Thus, he might have some reservations about his choice of side. He might not be sure that Robb would win the war.

> This is probably why he betrayed him later and joined the Lannister side.